# Is there an existing model for a ball on beam system?

Tags: control

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone, I have a couple of hours next week that I was planning to spend with our favorite simulation framework.
Before I started though, I wanted to check if there already was an existing model of a ball on beam, or a ball on plate system.

If not, I was going to follow [Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) assuming that still is how things are built in Gazebo these days.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12149/is-there-an-existing-model-for-a-ball-on-beam-system?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4121/markus/) on 2018-04-23**:
Hey SL REmy, did you build up a ball on plate system in gazebo and would you like to share  it??! 2f4yor@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know of an existing beam-on-ball system, or ball on plate system.

You can use URDF to create such a system, but I would recommend using [SDF](http://sdformat.org)  (here is a relevant [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model&cat=build_robot)). With SDF you can [contribute](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_contrib&cat=build_robot) your model into Gazebo's database, and SDF is the default format for Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0